# How to insert the last (space-delimited) string on the line above into the current line at the cursor in emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs24

While working in python I've sometimes found that I unnecessarily have a snippet like:

```
thing = longfunctioncall(with, many, necessary, arguments, that, take, a, fairly, long, time, to, type)
formattedthing = [str(*q) for q in thing]
```

That I can consolidate into:

```
formattedthing = [str(*q) for q in longfunctioncall(with, many, necessary, arguments, that, take, a, fairly, long, time, to type)]
```

I know that you can simply kill and yank the whole statement, but I was wondering if there was a more EMACSy way to do it.

Comment: I would, with point on the second line, transpose the lines `C-x C-t`, reposition point on second line `C-p`, merge them `M-^`, then fix by hand.